# Where are the language settings in the Xbox 360 version of Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

I've bought The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim in german store. Whole game use german language. But some time ago I've bought GTA: Episodes from Liberty City and I changed language in the menu. But how to do it in Skyrim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this isn't possible on the Xbox 360.

There have been a few posts from users in South American countries concerning something similar.

I have linked a few threads that I have found off the official Bethesda Skyrim forums addressing the same issue that you have: [here](http://forums.bethsoft.com/index.php?/topic/1281429-languague-in-the-game/), [here](http://forums.bethsoft.com/index.php?/topic/1282284-region-game/) and [here](http://forums.bethsoft.com/index.php?/topic/1278022-subtitles-issue/)

There is speculation that the language is actually on the disc but remains inactive. Bethesda has not officially commented on any of this though.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not good for me :( But maybe its possible to get patch from Live or something like that? I just need at least english subtitles.

Comment: Perhaps, but Bethesda do seem really quiet on the issue :(. It's possible to change the language on the Steam version by the Properties->Language tab (I have verified this), but it seems that they "region locked" the language in the console versions. Patch 1.2 comes soon, but it doesn't sound as if they are doing anything with the language issues, mainly just fixing bugs and slow down.

Comment: Understand. Maybe when they'll fix this bug I'll finish playing :)

Comment: I wonder if they left this off accidentally in their efforts to get things compressed down enough to fit on a single disc for the 360.

Comment: Seems likely, the installation sizes are as follows: PC - 5.6GB, PS3 - 5.5GB, XBOX360 - 3.8GB. However, it doesn't seem a lot to ask for a subtitle translation. I'm unsure of the status of the PS3 languages, but I do know when selecting a new language for the PC version on Steam that it requires a 1.4GB download. I've not verified whether this is additional or a replacement, but as it seems there is no language selection option then I assume it's a replacement as I had to go through a verify/re-download of English game files to fix it also.

Comment: I've googled about PS3. There are common problems as with Xbox version.